# Installation of turtlebot on ROS-lunar

Tags: ubuntu, ros

I'm trying to install turtlebot on **ROS-lunar** (ubuntu 17.04) but it keeps on giving me this error:

> E: Unable to locate package ros-lunar-turtlebot E: Unable to locate package 
>   ros-lunar-turtlebot-apps E: Unable to locate package
>   ros-lunar-turtlebot-interactions E: Unable to locate package
>   ros-lunar-turtlebot-simulator E: Unable to locate package
>   ros-lunar-kobuki-ftdi E: Unable to locate package
>   ros-lunar-rocon-remocon E: Unable to locate package
>   ros-lunar-rocon-qt-library

[image: error screenshot]

I tried all the solutions available on the internet, Please help.

Comment: Have you correctly [set up your sources](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2BAC8-Ubuntu.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list)?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: See the link in my question. Your system seems not able to find the packages you want to install. Hence the question; did you set it up so it can following the ROS installation instructions?

Comment: Yes, I have done all of those steps correctly.

Comment: Maybe you need to switch your Linux distribution, since turtlebot is not well supported in new version.  `ROS Indigo ONLY supports Saucy (13.10) and Trusty (14.04) for debian packages.`

Answer (score 1):

At the moment Lunar is the latest ROS distribution. TurtleBot team has not yet released a distribution for ROS-lunar (ubuntu 17.04). 
For more information: https://answers.ros.org/question/282114/how-i-can-install-turtlebot-on-ros-lunar/